# Attribute error: 'ReduceLROnPlateau' object has no attribute _cmp

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to load an existing pytorch model with -

```
from mymodels import model
m = torch.load("model.pth", map_location=torch.device("cpu"))
```

I'm getting the error -

> line 613, in _load
>
> result = unpickler.load()
>
> Attribute error: 'ReduceLROnPlateau' object has no attribute _cmp

my pytorch version is 1.3.1. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because of a version difference between the pytorch the network is trained on and the pytorch being used. It was resolved by using the same versions.